# Nginx overwrites general symfony errors with 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: symfony, nginx

When I try to access a non-existing route or make a mistake inside a Twig template, instead of getting the Symfony error page with debug information, I get redirected to a default nginx 502 Bad Gateway.

The log shows an interesting line:

```
013/07/17 16:11:41 [error] 16952#0: *187 upstream sent too big header while reading
response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ftwo.localhost, request: "GET    
/heasd HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "ftwo.localhost"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the relevant parts of your nginx logs ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Increase your buffer size in nginx configuration and restart nginx afterwards as suggested [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream).

```
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

Further increase the fastcgi buffer in the php section of your configuration ( location ~ .php$ )

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

Referenced answer to a question from a CodeIgniter user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894386/upstream-too-big-nginx-codeigniter).

Comment: That actually solved the issue. Thanks a lot. One quick question: the error page now doesn't load the layout correctly? Could that be related?

Comment: hm maybe a css/js issue ? what does your firebug/devtools netpanel say?

Comment: Just a note to say that reloading should suffice. (sudo service nginx reload) - Regarding the error pages not rendering, do you have problems elsewhere? Have you ran the assets install command?

Comment: I would like to say that it's really important you set the proxy buffer in nginx.conf and also the fastcgi settings in your vhost file.

Comment: if you have this error your browser most likely is Chrome. FF shows error pages OK. at least for me. so I guess both answers here are right. accepted one fixes the problem by increasing server buffers, another by disabling extra debugging feature.

Answer (score 17):

You may also try to disable ChromePHP at app/config/config_dev.yml

Just comment out these lines:

```
chromephp:
    type:   chromephp
    level:  info
```

This plugin generates a large header and forces nginx to response with 502 Bad Gateway.

More info at:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8413

[Enable Debug Component in Symfony 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445513/enable-debug-component-in-symfony-2-3)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem in 2023. I just install monolog

```bash
composer require symfony/monolog-bundle
```

After that, the 502 error disappeared, and debugging information began to be saved to `/var/log` in the project folder.

Comment: I also had nginx 502 errors when accessing the Symfony profiler and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have a dev environment set up in .env, it was a problem in my case.